# RPC (simulated) over DEALER-ROUTER socket pair: ordering reponses to match requests

Tags: node.js, zeromq

Sorry if the answer is obvious, but ...

Because the DEALER socket allows to send multiple message to a ROUTER without waiting for the answer, in case it is needed to match each answer  from ROUTER with its originating request from DEALER, (say, you are simulating RPC) then the programmer must implement (by hand) a numbering scheme associating request-number with a corresponding waiting callback,
to be called when the matching answer is arrived. OK?

Or it is anything in the (node.js) library of 0MQ to handle this?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library could be a solution:

[zerorpc](http://www.zerorpc.io)